# Read metadata from nupkg

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

Is there anyway to read the metadata of a NuGet-package-file?

I would really like to create a simple site for searching among my nupkg-files..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22):

The [NuGet.Core](http://nuget.org/packages/Nuget.Core/) package contains the official API for reading package metadata.

To read information about a single .nupkg file use code similar to following.

```
var myPackage = new ZipPackage(@"C:\Path\to\MyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg");

Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", myPackage.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", myPackage.Version);
Console.WriteLine(
    "Assemblies: {0}",
    myPackage.AssemblyReferences.Select(a => a.Name).ToArray());
```

There are also similar classes for reading Package sources (aka Feeds), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can access nugetCore API to access all the metadata, if you have nuget deployed in server.

```
using NuGet;
```

Sample Code

```
 IPackageRepository repo =
                PackageRepositoryFactory.Default.CreateRepository("https://nugetserver.sample/nuget");

            //Initialize the package manager
            string path = "../../xyx";
            PackageManager packageManager = new PackageManager(repo, path);

            var package = packageManager.SourceRepository.GetPackages()
                .OrderByDescending(p => p.Version).Where(p => p.Id == packageName).FirstOrDefault();


            var version = package.Version.ToFullString();
            var packageName = package.GetFullName();
```

Actual Code that does the job is below

```
var package = packageManager.SourceRepository.GetPackages()
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Version).Where(p => p.Id == packageName).FirstOrDefault();
```