# how can i get MetadataReference from nupkg package in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, roslyn

I want get MetadataReference from nupkg package  in dotnet

```
 //https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/nuget/reference/nuget-client-sdk
            using FileStream inputStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\Surface\\Downloads\\microsoft.office.interop.excel.15.0.4795.1001.nupkg", FileMode.Open);
            using PackageArchiveReader reader = new PackageArchiveReader(inputStream);
            NuspecReader nuspec = reader.NuspecReader;
            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {nuspec.GetId()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Version: {nuspec.GetVersion()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Description: {nuspec.GetDescription()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Authors: {nuspec.GetAuthors()}");
            Console.WriteLine("Dependencies:");
            foreach (PackageDependencyGroup dependencyGroup in nuspec.GetDependencyGroups())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" - {dependencyGroup.TargetFramework.GetShortFolderName()}");
                foreach (var dependency in dependencyGroup.Packages)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"   > {dependency.Id} {dependency.VersionRange}");
                }
            }
```

i find this code form msdn 。

but i want get MetadataReference like that

```
//from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138580/read-metadata-from-nupkg
var myPackage = new ZipPackage(@"C:\Path\to\MyPackage.1.0.0.nupkg");

Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}", myPackage.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", myPackage.Version);
Console.WriteLine(
    "Assemblies: {0}",
    myPackage.AssemblyReferences.Select(a => a.Name).ToArray());
```

but ZipPackage in NuGet.Core package , it not support dotnet6.

PS: Infact i want add nuget package when application is running.

try NuGet.Packaging  but not find suitable function

Answer (score 1):

You could use the analyzer testing library:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-sdk/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing/README.md

You can first get the ReferenceAssemblies for the TargetFramework you need, for example, net6.0, then set a `NuGet.config` file path <sup>[1]</sup>, then add the NuGet package you need by specifying its name and version. Then, to get the `MetadataReference`s, you can call `ResolveAsync`

```cs
var referenceAssemblies = ReferenceAssemblies.Net.Net60.WithNuGetConfigFilePath("path to NuGet.config").AddPackages(ImmutableArray.Create(new PackageIdentity("NuGetPackageId", "Version")));
var metadataReferences = await referenceAssemblies.ResolveAsync(null, default);
```

<sup>[1]</sup> The NuGet.config file you pass will contain an entry that points out to the local folder that contains the nupkg file. If you didn't do so, it will fall back to searching on NuGet.org.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static async Task<List<MetadataReference>> GetMetadataReferenceFormNugetPackageAsync(string path ,bool isAddToAppDomain=false)
    {
        if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        }
        List<MetadataReference> metadataReferences = null;
        Stream packageStream = null;
        if (path.StartsWith("http"))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(path);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            packageStream = new MemoryStream();
            await response.Content.CopyToAsync(packageStream);
        }
        else
        {
            packageStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        }
        //use NuGet.Packaging
        using PackageArchiveReader reader = new PackageArchiveReader(packageStream);
        NuspecReader nuspec = reader.NuspecReader;
        CommonLog.LogInfo($"get NugetPackage ： ID: {nuspec.GetId()} \nVersion: {nuspec.GetVersion()} \nDescription: {nuspec.GetDescription()} \nAuthors: {nuspec.GetAuthors()}");
        IEnumerable<FrameworkSpecificGroup> frameworkSpecificGroups =  reader.GetReferenceItems();
        FrameworkSpecificGroup frameworkSpecificGroup = null;
        foreach (string tempTargetFramework in availableFrameworkNames)
        {
            frameworkSpecificGroup = frameworkSpecificGroups.FirstOrDefault((item) => item.TargetFramework.DotNetFrameworkName == tempTargetFramework);
            if (frameworkSpecificGroup != null) break;
        }
        if (frameworkSpecificGroup != null)
        {
            if (frameworkSpecificGroup.Items?.Count() > 0)
            {
                metadataReferences = new List<MetadataReference>();
                foreach(string dllPath in frameworkSpecificGroup.Items)
                {
                    using (Stream dllStream = reader.GetStream(dllPath))
                    {
                        // create MetadataReference from the stream
                        using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            dllStream.CopyTo(memStream);
                            memStream.Position = 0;
                            MetadataReference metadataRef = MetadataReference.CreateFromStream(memStream);
                            //MetadataReference metadataRef2 = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
                            metadataReferences.Add(metadataRef);
                        }
                        // use the metadataRef in your compilation
                        // e.g. compilation.AddReferences(metadataRef);
                    }

                    //Add to AppDomain
                    if (isAddToAppDomain)
                    {
                        using (Stream dllStream = reader.GetStream(dllPath))
                        {
                            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                dllStream.CopyTo(memStream);
                                memStream.Position = 0;
                                int tempLen = (int)memStream.Length;
                                byte[] rawAssemblyBuffer = new byte[tempLen];
                                int tempReadLen = await memStream.ReadAsync(rawAssemblyBuffer, 0, rawAssemblyBuffer.Length);
                                if (tempReadLen != tempLen)
                                {
                                    CommonLog.LogError($"GetMetadataReferenceFormNugetPackageAsync-AddToAppDomain[{path}] error read len {tempReadLen}");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                   Assembly assembly =  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(rawAssemblyBuffer);
                                   //Type[] typeArray = assembly.GetTypes();
                                    //MyAssemblyHelper.AddAppDomainClassNameDc(assembly);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        packageStream?.Dispose();
        return metadataReferences;
    }
```

I find reader.GetStream(dllPath) and MetadataReference.CreateFromStream will be use.
this code has tested pass.